# Handling serial streams biggers than the available ram

Tags: serial, arduino-leonardo, eeprom

I need to parse text coming into my MC (Leonardo) over the hardware serial port. The data comes in burst, and the parsing routine manage the data flow with easy when it is less than the serial buffer.

I will like to be able to receive around 512Kb of serial data, save it somewhere (not in the arduino memory of course) and the execute the parsing routine on it. I think saving the stream to an external EEPROM and then retrieving it slowly so my parsing code can actually fallows will do the trick. I can control the speed of the serial stream from 300 bauds (not optimal) up to 112000 bauds.

Is the approach correct? Can I write to the EEPROM faster than a 9600 bauds serial stream without collapsing the arduino?

Comment: SD card would probably be a more sensible alternative.

Comment: Do you really need the all the data before you can parse it? Can't you parse it on-the-fly? Could you change the sender code so that it wait when the arduino is busy (send-ack pattern). EEPROM has a limited amount of write cycles, so it's not ideal. Serial RAM, like e.g. [23K256](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22100D.pdf), would be more appropriate. (though I can't tell if the arduino can write fast enough, as you asked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse indefinitely large amounts of data with a state machine parser.

General description: [State machines](http://www.gammon.com.au/statemachine)

As an example, I wrote recently an [HTTP server](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12942) which parses incoming HTTP data (eg. cookies, parameters, POST data, GET data) on-the-fly.

You need enough RAM for **one** item of data, naturally. But then you act upon it, and then discard it. In the case of the web server, you could conceivably process a complex form with thousands of actions on it (eg. turn on switch 5, pump 3, heater 22). It parses each action, and then you act on it, then you parse another action.

---

You can even consider the Arduino bootloader as an example of this. The Optiboot bootloader is 512 bytes on a Uno, but it can re-flash 32 KB of program memory. How? The programming data comes down in bursts (packets, if you like) and it processes each packet at a time, then discards it and reads the next one.

Comment: Hello @Nick! I keep seeing your name popping out in the Arduino forums and here in stackexhange always helping the comunity. Thank you!!!

Comment: @DomingoSL Nick's website is an excellent Arduino reference http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/index.php?bbtopic_id=123